# Uploading PDF to Amazon S3 and display in browser

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

```
const fs = require('fs');

const pdf = require('html-pdf');

const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

//Read html file
function readHTMLfile(path, callback) {

    fs.readFile(path, {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function(err, html) {

        if(err) {

            callback(err);
        }

        else {

            callback(null, html)

        }

    })

}

//importing HTML file
readHTMLfile(__dirname + '/Nda.html', function(err, html) {

    if(err) {
        console.log('Error: ',err)
    }

    else {
        var handlebars = require("handlebars");
        var template = handlebars.compile(html);
        var replacables = {
            url: 'http://politicalmemorabilia.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/2000px-Aaron_Burr_signature.png'
        } 
        var HtmlToSend = template(replacables);
        //pdf.create(HtmlToSend).toStream(function(err, stream){
        pdf.create(HtmlToSend).toBuffer(function(err, buf){
            if(err){
                return console.log(err);    
            } 
            else {
                console.log('This is a buffer:', buf);
                //stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./Nda2.pdf'));
              //var readableStream = fs.readFileSync('./Nda2.pdf', 'base64')
              // console.log('Readable Stream: ',readableStream)
              // var buf = new Buffer('readableStream', 'base64')
              // console.log('Buffer String ',buf.toString())
              //console.log('Readable Stream ',readableStream)
              //console.log('Pdf Content', ./Nda2.pdf);

                AWS.config.update({
                    accessKeyId: "AKIAIRJAKT756L72NPBA",
                    secretAccessKey: "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"
              });

            var s3Bucket = new AWS.S3({ params: { Bucket: "vizitor-profilepicture" } });

                var options = {
                Key: `nda/Nda`,
                Body: 'buf',
                ContentEncoding: "buffer",
                //ContentDisposition: "inline",
                ContentType: "application/pdf"
                };
                s3Bucket.upload(options, function(err, data) {
                  if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    console.log("Error uploading data: ", data);
                  } else {
                    console.log('Data: ',data)
                    console.log("data: ", data.Location);
                    console.log("succesfully uploaded pdf!");
                  }
                });     
            }
        });
    }
})
```

I am importing a HTML file and converted it into pdf using "html-pdf" module and used handlebars to embed dynamic URL in HTML file.I then converted the HTML file to buffer and want to upload to amazon s3 as pdf. For this, I have used buffer in body option. I am getting the correct buffer but when I upload to amazon s3 as pdf file a link is generated but on opening link in browser I get an error "Failed to load pdf"

I have made s3 bucket for public view so that's not the issue here.

Comment: Can you add a bit more about what you are trying to do and what problems you encountered. As it stands, your question is mostly code.

Comment: I am importing a HTML file and converted it into pdf using "html-pdf" module and used handlebars to embed dynamic URL in HTML file in  <img> tag.I then converted the HTML file to buffer and want to upload to amazon s3. For this, I have used buffer in body option. I am getting the correct buffer but when I upload to amazon s3 as pdf file a link is generated but on opening link in browser I get an error "Failed to load pdf"

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include further information.

Comment: Please check the question @RalfStubner

Comment: did you got the answer?